# How to install kali Linux on an external hard disk?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, linux-kernel, kali-linux, user-mode-linux

My machine is running MintOs, I want to install kali Linux on my external hard disk. What are the steps to be followed for doing such setup and how to boot kali OS from my external hard disk?

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Exchange! I'm glad you got an answer, but in the future, please don't post broad questions like this one. make an effort to do it yourself and if you run into a specific problem, come here and ask it, making sure to provide lots of details on what you've already tried. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Get a partition software.
2. Plug in the drive and the partition it to the size you prefer. Make sure that this partition is at least 10 GB's.
3. Make sure to also make a swap partition . This part doesn't have to be more than a few gigs.
4. Download a copy of Kali Linux (make sure its Kali Linux 2 since the first ones repositories aren't supported anymore).
5. Next, to install the OS, you can:

   - Use a virtual drive to access the ISO file and use that to install the OS, or
   - Burn the ISO onto a CD, or
   - Burn the ISO onto a USB with the help of software like [Etcher](https://etcher.io/).
6. Once the installer has started, scroll down to "Graphical Install".
7. Follow the on screen instructions until you reach the “erase everything, select drive, etc.” part. Select the advanced settings.
8. Once you have the reached the screen where you can select what drive you can install the OS, make sure that you have the external drive selected and select the partition you had made previously and make it your root.
9. Select the second extra partition for your swap space.
10. Continue the rest of the installation as you normally would.
11. Once the installation is complete, restart you computer, and boot into the boot manager, normally it's F12, Delete, or F8 (The bios screen will tell you which key it is).
12. With your external hard drive plugged in, select it and you should be able to boot from it.
13. Start up the OS as you would any other.

If you follow these steps carefully your internal drive and Mint-OS installation should stay untouched.

Comment: If I helped you please simply click on ✓
[How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Hi @Luka. I tried this same proceedure but the drive is not recognized in boot. any sugestions ?

Comment: Change BIOS boot setting from UEFI to LEGACY and also make sure your first boot device is that disk